# Backorder option on special products

Tags: magento-1.6, backorder

I need to add the ability to back order specific products on my Magento 1.6.2 website.
Inventory is controlled by magento, so when a product sells, the quantity in stock is reduced accordingly. When stock reaches zero, it is marked as out of stock.

I have the back order settings as follows:

System > Config > Inventory > Backorders = Not allowed (the correct general rule for the entire site).

Catalog > Edit Product > Inventory > Backorders = Allow below 0 and notify.

I have written code to display the relevant add to cart/backorder/notify me button - and this is working fine:

```
<?php if((int)$inventory->getQty()>0 && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>

                    <a class="form-button" style="text-decoration:none" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('Add To Cart');?></a>

                <?php elseif($inventory->getBackorders()>0): ?>

                    <a class="backorder form-button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('Back Order');?></a>

                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php 
                    $alertUrl = $this->getUrl().'/productalert/add/stock/product_id/'.$_product->getId().$pageUrl;
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $alertUrl;?>" class="notify"><?php echo $this->__('Notify Me');?></a>

                <?php endif; ?>
```

On my development website (a direct replica of my live website) this all works great and the back ordered item is added to the cart, and the notification text appears on the cart page as expected.

When I push the code live, the buttons appear correctly as expected, but I cannot add the back ordered item to my cart. Instead I get the message "This product is currently out of stock."

I do not understand why the two websites are behaving differently for the same test on the same product? The website settings are the same, except for no caching on the dev site.
I have reindexed and recached the live site, but this same error message keeps appearing.

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Cheers!

Comment: Is the product on your production server under the Inventory tab also marked as out of stock? If so save it again as "in stock".

Comment: Hi, Yes it is marked as out of stock. If I mark it as in stock, the back order button becomes an add to cart button.

Comment: I thought I had tried the above suggestion, but have come back to this today and tried it, and it works!! I'm really not sure why, but mainly, I'm not sure why this needs to be done on the LIVE site but not on the DEV site which is a direct copy/replica of the LIVE site? Very wierd - but seemingly working! :-) Thanks again.